# MemCache-repcached compile error

Tags: linux, php, cache, memcache, operating-system

I'm trying to install [memcached-1.2.8-repcached-2.2.1](
http://sourceforge.net/projects/repcached/files/latest/download?source=files)

And I have the following error after running the `make` command:

> make  all-recursive
>
> make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/pro/memcached-1.2.8-repcached-2.2.1'
>
> Making all in doc
>
> make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/pro/memcached-1.2.8-repcached-2.2.1/doc'
>
> make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
>
> make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/pro/memcached-1.2.8-repcached-2.2.1/doc'
>
> make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/pro/memcached-1.2.8-repcached-2.2.1'
>
> gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG   -g -O2 -MT memcached-memcached.o -MD -MP -MF 
>   .d> eps/memcached-memcached.Tpo -c -o memcached-memcached.o `test -f 'memcached.c' || echo 
>   './'`memcached.c
>
> memcached.c: In function ‘add_iov’:
>
> memcached.c:697: error: ‘IOV_MAX’ undeclared (first use in this function)
>
> memcached.c:697: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
>
> memcached.c:697: error: for each function it appears in.)
>
> make[2]: *** [memcached-memcached.o] Error 1
>
> make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/pro/memcached-1.2.8-repcached-2.2.1'
>
> make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
>
> make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/pro/memcached-1.2.8-repcached-2.2.1'
>
> make: *** [all] Error 2

OS : Centos5.7 64bit

gcc-4.1.2-51.el5

gcc-c++-4.1.2-51.el5

libgcc-4.1.2-51.el5

Note : Memcached and memcache extension for php are already installed

> root@server[~]# memcached -h
>
> memcached 1.4.5

php ext http://pecl.php.net/get/memcache-2.2.6.tgz

Comment: Have you tried `yum install memcached` ...?

Comment: @KM01 memcached is already installed and the memcache extension for php also.

My Problem within memcached-repcached

Comment: Oops, sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem and this is one of the top results in Google, so was forced to do some digging and testing.

Finally I managed to get it to work. The trick is to install libevent1 **not** libevent2.

In ubuntu I did:

```
sudo apt-get install libevent1-dev
```

I had also previously installed the default libevent-dev which is libevent2, so I purged this:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge libevent-dev
```

I have a feeling this may be a bit late for the original poster, but may hopefully help someone else out there.